# HDD External can't be recognized on office PC

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-xp, external-hard-drive

So don't know what's wrong
Before it works fine
Now I can't access HDD external from office PC
I try to use 2 different PC not work(windows 10)
I try at home with my laptop it's work (windows XP)

WD 4 TB external my passport (like 4-5 years probably forgot it kinda old)

Is my HDD broken or PC get virus or what happen?
Thanks

Comment: Do other USB storage devices still work on your office PC? If not may be the admins have done something to disable USB storage devices like USB HDDs or thumb drives.

Comment: Never try with other HDD but I have been tried with phone and use it as storage an it worked

Comment: The Passport series require power through USB. Perhaps there is a power limitation, e.g., other USB devices have been added at office. Have you tried different ports? USB 3.0 can provide far more current than USB 2.0.

Comment: Phones use MTP protocol, that is totally different than USB storage protocol(s) as used by USB thumb drives or HDDs.